What does "spiked with coughing death" mean in "The Odyssey"?
In The Odyssey, when Penelope becomes convinced that Odysseus is not going to return, she devises a test for the suitors: to use Odysseus' bow to shoot an arrow through twelve axes. When she goes to get the bow, we are given this description:

Now Penélopê sank down, holding the weapon on her knees, and drew her husband’s great bow out, and sobbed and bit her lip and let the salt tears flow. Then back she went to face the crowded hall tremendous bow in hand, and on her shoulder hung the quiver spiked with coughing death. Behind her maids bore a basket full of axeheads, bronze and iron implements for the master’s game.
The Odyssey, chapter 21, translation by Robert Fitzgerald (1961), lines 54–62

What is the quiver "spiked with coughing death"? I presume this refers to the arrows stored within the quiver, but why would they be "coughing" death? Does this have something to do with Apollo's arrows of disease, such as the incident in the beginning of The Iliad where Apollo is described as shooting arrows at the Greeks to cause disease?

The difficult line is 21.60:

… πολλοὶ δ᾽ ἔνεσαν στονόεντες ὀϊστοί
many groan-causing arrows were in it [the quiver]
Homer. Odyssey 21.60. My translation.

The arrows are described as στονόεντες, for which Liddell & Scott give the meaning “causing groans or sighs”, from στοναχέω meaning “groan, sigh”. The implication in 21.60, I think, is that the groans will come from those wounded by the arrows, and the sighs from the loved ones of those slain by the arrows. I’ve used “groan-causing” in my translation above to demonstrate the literal meaning, but of course that’s not idiomatic in English: depending on the context you could use “deadly”, “grievous”, “mournful” and so on.
The word is also used at 11.383:

οἳ Τρώων μὲν ὑπεξέφυγον στονόεσσαν ἀυτήν
who fled from the groan-causing cry of the Trojans
Odyssey 11.383. My translation.

For comparison, A. T. Murray (1919) translated στονόεσσαν as “dread” at 11.383, which is more idiomatic in English. At 21.60 he used “fraught with groanings”. Other things that are “groan-causing” in the Odyssey are Odysseus’s grief (κήδεα) at 9.12 and Penelope’s bed (εὐνήν) at 17.102.
Fitzgerald’s choice of “coughing” is a bit difficult to defend. I think the idea may be that the shooting of arrows is to be compared to the expulsion of air when coughing. And “coughing” is in the same kind of semantic area as “groaning and sighing”. “Coughing” is sometimes used to describe the firing of guns, though that is mainly a similarity of sound which would not apply to the shooting of arrows.
It seems that Fitzgerald was committed to not repeating himself, so that each time a Homeric epithet or line recurred, as it often did, he had to find a new variation of wording. He had already used “quills of groaning” for στονόεντες ὀϊστοί at 21.12, so when the phrase recurred at 21.60 he needed a new translation, and maybe inspiration failed him on this occasion.

"coughing" seems like an unusual word to use, then; do you have any idea why Fitzgerald may have chosen that term?

Out of interest my 2017 translation by Emily Wilson omits this descriptor, opting for "quiver, packed with many deadly arrows" instead

@MattThrower Wilson translated στονόεντες as "deadly": as with Murray's "dread", this is a good idiomatic equivalent.
